# Convert RGB array to Mat (OpenCv)

Tags: c, opencv, rgb, mat

I've been trying to convert an array `[R,G,B,..]` in Mat object with opencv. But is returning wrong data, someone knows why?

```
double data[12] = {0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255};
Mat src =  Mat(2,2, CV_16UC3, data);
```

and returns:

```
M = 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
  0, 0, 0, 0, 57344, 16495]
```

EDIT:

Solved! use uchar instead double, and CV_8UC3

Comment: I think this question has the wrong title. Shouldn't it be RGB instead of RGBA?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i think, you wanted:

```
uchar data[12] = {0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255,0,0,255};
Mat src =  Mat(2,2, CV_8UC3, data);
```

(all red, 2x2 rbg image)